Bash / ZSH script that can be run as one click exe/app for other Mac users
I have a bash script and the only way I get others to run it is by sharing the code to them or asking them to open the terminal and then do "bash filename.sh". Instead of this, I would like to offer a one click app or one click exe kind of solution where no one needs to do anything other than clicking on the file - which I can share with other Mac users.
Can someone please guide me on how to achieve this ?

Save the script in a file with the filename extension '.command' and set the executable bits; e.g.
chmod +x foo.command


TIL. Cool, thanks.

Can you please share an example ?
Say this is my bash script
echo "Hello World"
Sleep 4
and the script is saved as "network.sh"
so do I need to add "chmod +x foo.command" to the script ?
Also, will this run normally on other Mac devices ? I want to share my script with folks who are unable to do open terminal run in manually and can only do one click run like the Mac apps

Add an interpreter line to the beginning of the script, such as ‘#!/bin/sh’. Rename it ‘network.command’ and set the executable bits as above. When double-clicked in the Finder, it will open a Terminal window and execute. Depending on how you distribute it, the user may get a quarantine warning.

Take a look at Platypus.
From the linked page:

Platypus is a developer tool that creates native Mac applications from command line scripts such as shell scripts or Python, Perl, Ruby, Tcl, JavaScript and PHP programs. This is done by wrapping the script in a macOS application bundle along with an app binary that runs the script.
Platypus makes it easy to share scripts and command line programs with people who are unfamiliar with the shell interface. Native, user-friendly applications can be created with a few clicks. It is very easy to create installers, droplets, administrative applications, login items, status menu items, launchers and automations using Platypus.

Free and Open Source.

Or just use Apple's automated

Do you mean Automator? :-) I hesitate to recommend it because it seems Automator is not long for the world, to be replaced by Shortcuts. I hope I'm wrong though.

Yes, you can use Automator or Shortcuts to run a script or other command. You can even have the Shortcut appear in the menubar where you can select it from anywhere.
